# If a professor accepts me as a PhD student, does their offer bypass the committee's selection?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states

I'm applying for Ph.D. this year. As far as I know, many universities are **strong-committee**, i.e. one has to pass the committee so that he/she could get a Ph.D. offer. But when I contacted one professor at **Yale** (which is also strong-committee), the professor guaranteed that if I apply, he will accept me. I'm wondering, can I count on this **oral offer**? how sure should I feel about this Ph.D. offer? Would new professors have the privilege of choosing the students they want, **bypassing the committee**?

Comment: I doubt that the committee can be bypassed. He probably means that "if you are accepted into the program, I'm willing to be your advisor."

Comment: I like this question, can anyone figure out a better title?

Comment: @Dawn I edited the title, what do you think? OP, I added the `united-states` tag, but feel free to add another country tag if you are applying elsewhere (admissions processes are different in different countries).

Comment: @astronat Yes! I think that will be much easier for future searchers to find!

Answer (score 10):

> can I count on this oral offer?

No. This is not an official offer from a graduate program and you should not count on anything that isn’t an official offer. It’s certainly nice and somewhat reassuring to have an informal promise of this type, but that’s all it is. Individual people are occasionally careless with their words and are known to break promises occasionally, so you should not treat this as a sure thing.

> how sure should I feel about this Ph.D. offer?

Reasonably confident, but hold off on popping the champagne. You will live long enough to see various low probability events happen. The possibility that a formal PhD offer will not materialize in this situation is a low probability event, but not a zero probability event.

Answer (score 7):

In the US, if a professor had the actual power to admit a student into a doctoral program it would be extremely unusual. Professors are employees, not officers, of the institution, so would need to be granted explicit power for this. It is the institution that grants degrees, not the advisor, though in some fields the advisor provides funding for students.

Likely what is intended is that if you get accepted (by the committee) he will be happy to be your advisor.

Some professors might have some informal influence over committees, but not much more than that.

It is encouraging, however, but you have to make a formal application.

Comment: Sometimes there's a different bar for "students we want to admit" and "students we can fund", where the university only really extends offers of admission to the second category, but a professor willing to pay can get students in the first category through. Still need to pass that hurdle, though, and that's nothing a professor can guarantee.

Comment: Could be the prof is fairly confident that they can persaude the rest of the comittee?

Comment: @IanSudbery, it could also be explained by arrogance, unfortunately.

Comment: @IanSudbery Confident/arrogant - often the same thing. Just because you are "confident" doesn't mean you are correct.

Comment: I think this varies across institutions.  At Michigan, my understanding was that if a professor had money to cover a student, they could pluck the applicant out of the list on their own.

Comment: I feel things could vary a lot across different programs. My intuition is that well-funded faculties (e.g., in CS/EE) may have a larger freedom than those who are mainly funded by the department/institution (e.g., math/stats in many schools). But not sure if well-fundedness can be translated to bypassing the committee.

Comment: @BrianKrause "that's nothing a professor can guarantee" What if they're the committee chair/head of school/the boss, and they can just instruct the committee to take you on as a student?

Comment: @nick012000, unlikely. Department organization doesn't really work like that in US. Doing so would indicate a breakdown.

Comment: @nick012000 It's possible in some systems the chair of a graduate program has some power like that, but not in the US systems I am familiar with. Department/program chairs are closer to peers of their fellow faculty than they are a "boss", and admissions is typically by a committee that they don't necessarily even head or stand on.